# Any actual Python libraries to work with VmWare VIX API?

Tags: python, vmware, vix

Anybody here uses such a library? Or using **`ctypes`** with `VIX API` dll is enough for the task of managing VMWare images?

What do you think and what you can suggest based on your experience? Is there any active and up-to-date solution written in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [`pysphere`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysphere/0.1.7), [`vix`](https://github.com/naim94a/vix) fit.

It's updated to the last version of [`VMware API`](http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html), and it's been developed and maintainted for a while now.

Even though for really complex scripts you should use the official bindings for powershell: [`VMWare PowerCLI`](http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/server/vsphere/automationtools/powercli).

Comment: It seems to me that you're compromising. `pysphere` is great, even though for complex scripts you should probably use the official bindings for powershell: PowerCLI. If your script is simple you should be fine with `pysphere`.

Comment: If this answer helped with your decision, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the official library released by VMware instead: [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi). It mirrors the [vSphere Web Services SDK](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/) and works in Python 2 or 3.

There's a discussion here: [What is the Difference between PySphere and PyVmomi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326448/what-is-the-difference-between-pysphere-and-pyvmomi)

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. The library was released just a few months ago.

Answer (score 1):

If your VirtualMachine objects are part of a vSphere environment you should use pyVmomi and use the GuestOperations. VIX has actually been deprecated from vSphere https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/VIX-1.14-ReleaseNotes.html#Deprecate and should really only be used for Fusion or Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I used [ctypesgen](https://github.com/davidjamesca/ctypesgen) to generate a ctypes wrapper for the VIX dylib and wrote some helper classes (Host, VM, Job, etc.). I use it to revert VMs to named snapshots and run scripts in the guest.